# mosquitto does not resend message when subscriber reconnects

Tags: java, mqtt, paho

I am working with eclipse paho and mosquitto. I am sending message with QOS-1 level. I've changed mosquitto configuration as answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38932479/published-message-store-by-mosquitto-broker-when-subscriber-is-offline-with-qos) question.I am using mqtt lens to test. Mosquitto does not send message after disconnection and connection of subscriber.

Comment: What's QOS are you subscribing to the messages? Are you using the same client id for the subscriber? Is the clean session flag set to false?

Comment: I've used QOS 1 while subscribing. Yeah client id  remains same. I've set clean session flag true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting clean session to `true` will tell the broker to remove any messages queued for the client.

You need to set it to `false` if you want to receive any messages queued for that client.

The guys at HiveMQ have a blog post about persistent sessions and message queueing with MQTT: http://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-7-persistent-session-queuing-messages

Comment: It worked. In case when subscriber explicitly disconnects with broker on client reconnection i'm getting same message 2 times.